# Adding a counter ID to a setInterval loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with three functions:

- `startBubbleMachine()` starts the process of making bubbles
- `makeBubble()` makes a bubble with a `bubbleID` to identify it. Appends to a div.
- `killBubble()` removes the bubble

The timings for the creation of the bubbles are randomised using another function `randomInt` which just generates a random int within a range.

I'm really struggling with the incrementing of `bubbleID`, which is needed to create the new bubble and to ensure the correct bubble is destroyed. I cannot work out at which stage to increment.

```
function startBubbleMachine(){
        console.log('starting bubble machine');
        var bubbleID = 1;
        setInterval(makeBubble(bubbleID), randomInt(6000, 1000));
    }
```

This function is pretty simple. It initialises `bubbleID`and then sets an interval between 1s and 6s to call `makeBubble()`, passing the `bubbleID`

This is where I get stuck

```
function makeBubble(bubbleID){
        console.log('making bubble number '+bubbleID);
        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="db-bubble db-bubble-'+bubbleID+'></div>');
        killBubble(bubbleID); // kill the bubble with the current ID
        bubbleID++; // increment the current ID
    }
```

The bubble is made, then the `killBubble()` function is called immediately. It passes the `bubbleID` to ensure the correct bubble will be murdered.

And then it increments the `bubbleID` ready for the next bubble creation. **But this bit is wrong, I'm sure.**

Finally, `killBubble()` has received the `bubbleID` it must murder. Waits for 2s, then removes.

```
function killBubble(bubbleID){
        setTimeout(function(){
            // murder time
            $(".db-bubble-"+bubbleID).remove();
        }, 2000);
        // this kills the bubble
    }
```

My issue is that **the process only runs once**. Bubble 1 is created, Bubble 1 is removed. *Bubble 2 never gets created.*

## [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn6jv9x/1/)

Comment: `setInterval(makeBubble(bubbleID)` you are using the function returned result as interval callback, which is `undefined`. See how you do it for the timeout..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/5w1np7zd/1/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `setInterval` this way:

```
setInterval(makeBubble(bubbleID), randomInt(6000, 1000));
```

It takes a function as a argument so it should be:

```
setInteval(function() {
    makeBubble(bubbleID);
}, randomInt(6000, 1000));
```

This [**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn6jv9x/4/) works for me.

You need to understand that your `bubbleID` is not being increased as it is passed `by value`. You should make it global.

```
var bubbleID;

function startBubbleMachine(){
    console.log('starting bubble machine');
    bubbleID = 1;
    setInterval(function() { makeBubble(bubbleID); }, randomInt(6000, 1000));
}
```

Also, as I guess, you want bubbles to appear randomly in that interval. You should understand that `randomInt(6000, 1000)` is **NOT** being calculated every time.

This is what actually happens:

```
var temp = randomInt(6000, 1000);
setInterval(function() { ... }, temp);
```

You need to change timer logic in order to make it work this way.

This is how I would do this: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn6jv9x/7/).

Answer (score 0):

As well as using `setInterval`, `bubbleID` is being passed by value (only objects are passed by reference) into the `makeBubble` funnction. Use a different name for your global counter than the parameter name in the `makeBubble` function.

Comment: Also be aware that if you're generating the bubbles at random intervals, you might have a bubble you generated earlier, running later than one you generated later... so mutiple bubbles would end up with the same ID. The whole thing needs a bit of a rethink.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit late still https://jsfiddle.net/arunzo/Lhn6jv9x/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    startBubbleMachine();
});
var bubbleID = 1;
function startBubbleMachine() {
    console.log('starting bubble machine');

    var rInt = randomInt(6000, 1000); 
    setInterval(function () {makeBubble()}, rInt);
}

function makeBubble() {
    var wh = randomInt(143, 50);
    console.log('making bubble number ' + bubbleID);
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="db-bubble db-bubble-' + bubbleID + '" style="transform:rotate(' + randomInt(20, 1) + 'deg);left:' + randomInt(100, 1) + '%;width:' + wh + 'px;height:' + wh + 'px;"></div>');
    killBubble(bubbleID);
    bubbleID++;
}

function killBubble(bubbleID) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('killing bubble number ' + bubbleID);
        // murder time
        $(".db-bubble-" + bubbleID).remove();
    }, 2000);
    // this kills the bubble
}


function randomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

}
```

since the function is being passed the value one in first instance it keeps running with the value 1 all the time. Remove it and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/Lhn6jv9x/8/

Move `bubbleID` to global scope by removing `var` and correct the `setInterval` format

```
 function startBubbleMachine() {
    console.log('starting bubble machine');
    bubbleID = 1;
    setInterval(function () {
        makeBubble(bubbleID)
    }, randomInt(6000, 1000));
}
```